# Regular expression to match string of 0's and 1's without '011' substring

Tags: regex, compiler-construction, grammar, automata

I'm working on a problem (from *Introduction to Automata Theory, Languages and Computer* by Hopcroft, Motwani and Ullman) to write a regular expression that defines a language consisting of all strings of `0`s and `1`s not containing the substring `011`.

Is the answer `(0+1)* - 011` correct ? If not what should be the correct answer for this?

Comment: If you are giving up after an hour, I suggest you try harder and do some searching.

Comment: I'm not giving you the answer but try this: Draw a finite state machine (graph) that accepts 011 as an input and then negate it (all accepting states are none accepting and none accepting are accepting). You should be able to solve the regular expression from there as it also is a finite state machine.

Comment: Well that same trick works for that as well, Draw a finite state machine (graph) that accepts any string that contains 011 ...

Answer (score 10):

[image: Automata diagram]
Edit: Updated to include start states and fixes, as per below comments.

Comment: As you mentioned automata, I thought I'd draw some, as they're so fun! :). Both are deterministic finite state. I'll be happy to answer questions on their construction if they're not explanatory enough. (Or correct any mistakes). Hope this helps!

Comment: You have no arrow indicating the starting states! (-1 from the teacher)
But we'll assume the leftmost shall we. The second is right on the money, the first is wrong. If you only accept exactly 011, all the arrows towards the leftmost state should go toward the righmost state in stead, because in those cases 011 can never be achieved any more.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I have fixed the image. It would have previously rejected (some) strings that ended in 011.

Comment: I don't think your first graph is correct, when it reaches the last state, 011 will be accepted.

Comment: @Blake you're right; that's the machine for "all except exactly the string 011". The original question was unclear as to which the OP was looking for. The 2nd machine more closely matches the question as stands.

Comment: Can you also add a regular expression for this case

Comment: Hey @PrasannaSasne; other answers have this already. What case are you looking for exactly?

Comment: I am looking for a regex for the same condition which you have implemented in DFA.

Comment: Everything except 011? `^(?!(.*?011$)).*$`

Answer (score 5):

If you are looking for all strings that do not have `011` as a substring rather than simply excluding the string `011`:

A classic regex for that would be:

```
1*(0+01)*
```

Basically you can have as many ones at the beginning as you want, but as soon as you hit a zero, it's either zeros, or zero-ones that follow (since otherwise you'd get a zero-one-one).

A modern, not-really-regular regex would be:

```
^((?!011)[01])*$
```

---

IF, however, you want any string that is not `011`, you can simply enumerate short string and wildcard the rest:

```
λ+0+1+00+01+10+11+(1+00+010)(0+1)*
```

And in modern regex:

```
^(?!011)[01]*$
```

Comment: `λ+0+1+00+01+10+11+(1+00+010)(0+1)*` how did you reach to this RE?

Comment: The first part is an enumeration of all strings that are shorter than 3 chars. The second part are strings with which `011` can't start, followed by arbitrary data.

Comment: Your answer is wrong. 1*(0+01)* does not accept 10, nor does it accept 101.

Comment: your answer `1*(0+01)*` how it will not accept 011. can you please explain?

Comment: @PrasannaSasne You can use https://regexr.com to explain the parts of the regex. In short, `1*(0+01)*` does not match `011` as the only `1`s it accepts are a `1` at the start (`1*` in the regex) or a `1` that is also prefixed by a `0` (the `01` in the `(0+01)*` regex)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the regular expression:

`0^* ∣1 + 0^∗ ∣0^* 01 + 0^*`

Answer (score 0):

The simplest to code (and understand) is:

```
^(?!.*011)[10]*$
```

This is a negative look ahead `(?!.*011)` for the prohibited substring, and composed of 1's and 0's `[10]*` (change to `[10]+` if blank is not a pass)